# With no optimization, C function only called once

Tags: c, optimization, g++

I'm running the latest cygwin with the g++ included.

It appears to me that a function call is being optimized out, even though the compiler flags include -O0.

The function is called from this loop (all code is simplified for the example):

```
void my_func ( void )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var1 = table[i];
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        function_to_call();
        printf("Called the function\n");
     }
}
```

The function it calls is like:

```
void function_to_call()
{
   int internal_var = var1;
   // do some math using internal_var, passing the result
   // as an input to another function

   printf("var1: %d\n", internal_var);
}
```

Running this, the output would be:

```
i = 0
var1 = 0
Called the function
i = 1
Called the function
```

Why is this happening? I want function_to_call() to be called every time through the loop. Here's an excerpt from the compiler output, taken directly from stdout:

```
 g++ -O0 -Wall -Wno-write-stings -Wextra
```

Comment: where is `var1` defined?

Comment: does `function_to_call` have any return cases?

Comment: Optimizer or not, the compiler can't omit that function call (well, can't omit calling printf). I suspect there's a problem in some of the code you're not showing.

Comment: And `function_to_call` doesn't have any `return` statements? Add a `printf` call at the _beginning_ of the function to see if it gets called or not, having one at the end is not much use to see if it gets called.

Comment: This other function, the one that function_to_call calls, does it throw an exception?  Is there a try/catch you aren't showing?  I noticed you tagged this as `C` not `C++` but you are using g++, so just wondering.

Comment: I think you'd need to post actual code that exhibits the problem to get an answer that's not speculation.

Comment: The output shown does NOT match the code provided.
Show the REAL code with its ACTUAL output.

Comment: Add to your compile and link flags `-g` then run the program to prove to yourself that nothing has changed. Then run that same binary in the debugger with a breakpoint on `function_to_call` to prove to yourself that the problem is not what you've described.

Comment: You are running cygwin on Windows, is that correct? If so, it is also likely that your // do some math causes the problem to crash. Windows now just terminates the process quietly if the program crashes due to access violation etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you posted is only "part" of the picture, as the `function_to_call()` outputs a `var1: ...` while your example output is `var1 = ...`.  Still, if I had to take a stab at the problem....

```
void function_to_call()
{
   int internal_var = var1;
   // do some math using internal_var, passing the result
   // as an input to another function

   printf("var1: %d\n", internal_var);
}
```

I would guess that the "do some math..." section is forcing an early return; but, only when the input (probably passed as a global variable in `var1`) is set to particular values.

Answer (score 0):

You folks were correct that I posted an incomplete code sample. The function does not actually have any return statements, but I found the culprit. The code in function_to_call() is in a state machine. What was happening is that the state was changed before that code completed, so the next time through it entered a different case.  My apologies to all, and lesson learned. I appreciate your efforts.